# Parse all PDF pages at once with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to parse a pdf file with "iText". What I am trying to achieve is to parse all pages at once.

```
try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:\\hl_sv\\L04MF.pdf");
            int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

            String content = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= pages; i++) {
                    System.out.println("============PAGE NUMBER " + i + "=============" );
                    content = content + " " +      PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);

            }
            System.out.println(content);

    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:77)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(PdfTextExtractor.java:74)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(PdfTextExtractor.java:89)
    at com.pdf.PDF.main(PDF.java:18)
```

Other problem I am facing is that the `-` hyphen is being parsed as `?` question mark. How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**Edit**
It works for me like this but I cant still solve the hyphen bug.

```
try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:\\hl_sv\\L04MF.pdf");
            int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

            for(int i = 1; i<= pages; i++) {
                    System.out.println("============PAGE NUMBER " + i + "=============" );
                    String line = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,i);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
    }
```

Comment: It is not *guaranteed* that all text is always readable from all PDFs. Your 'hyphen bug' may not be a bug in iText at all. But without an example file, no one can tell. If you post a link to a file that exhibits this particular problem, others can take a look.

Comment: Thank you, this question helped me, basically getTextFromPage(reader,i) has to have an i > 0 otherwise you get null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String extractPdfText() throws IOException {
  PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("/path/to/file/myfile.pdf");
  int pages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
  String pdfText = "";
  for (int ctr = 1; ctr < pages + 1; ctr++) {
    pdfText += PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, ctr); // Page number cannot be 0 or will throw NPE
  }
  pdfReader.close();
  return pdfText;
}
```